# How is he? or How is him?

Tags: pronouns

In a question like "How are you?", the pronoun is after a verb (to be) and I know that after verbs it's necessary to use objective pronouns. Then, which one is correct: "How is he?" or "How is him?"?.

Comment: Do we reply "*Him is well*" or "*Me is well, thank you*"? Maybe... in some dialects but not in Standard English.

Comment: "He" is the subject of the sentence; saying anything else would be ridiculous.

Answer (score 2):

You must say "How is he?"

You are wrong that "after verbs it's necessary to use objective pronouns".  You use objective pronouns for pronouns that aren't subjects.  The subject in this question comes after the verb because in questions the verb (or auxiliary verb) comes before the subject:

> He is a farmer ->  Is he a farmer?

Moreover, with a question pronoun like "what", that pronoun is fronted, it comes before the verb.

> He is a farmer -> Is he a farmer> -> What is he?

It is the same with "How".  The subject is "He", it comes after the verb "is" in the question and the question pronoun comes first.